# Running QGIS3 on Mac, multiple plugin problems, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

Couldn't load plugin 'Qgis2threejs' due to an error when calling its `classFactory()` method.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 337, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/__init__.py", line 27, in classFactory
    from .qgis2threejs import Qgis2threejs
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/qgis2threejs.py", line 29, in 
    from .q3dviewercontroller import Q3DViewerController
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/q3dviewercontroller.py", line 23, in 
    from .export import ThreeJSExporter
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/export.py", line 28, in 
    from .exportdem import DEMLayerExporter
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/exportdem.py", line 30, in 
    from .propertyreader import DEMPropertyReader
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/propertyreader.py", line 27, in 
    from .qgis2threejscore import calculateDEMSize
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/Qgis2threejs/qgis2threejscore.py", line 25, in 
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'


Python version: 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] 
QGIS version: 3.2.2-Bonn Bonn, exported 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/indyatblake/Desktop/QGIS/Workshop
/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin
/Users/indyatblake/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/vrtbuilderplugin/vrtbuilder
```

Comment: Hi Kadir I ran that, but still not sure what i'm doing wrong. I don't really know a great deal about coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the most recent GDAL framework from https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/. Then restart QGIS.

I had the same problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of issues getting osgeo running as well... conda install finally did the trick for me (running Windows, but my issues were similar).

This guy wrote a pretty helpful guide, in case you haven't already seen it: https://hackernoon.com/install-python-gdal-using-conda-on-mac-8f320ca36d90